# LWJGL not rendering my mesh, only the glClear color

Tags: java, opengl, rendering, lwjgl

I have a program written in lwjgl, and it's meant to render a cube, with each vertex colored differently. The problem I'm having is that it doesn't render the cube at all. Nothing shows up, why? I'm using a 2 VBOs, with consecutive position and color data in one, and indices in another, and they're bound into one VAO, which is *supposed* to be drawn.

```
private void initGLdata(String[] shaders, String[] uniforms) {
    //vertex buffer initialization
    verBufId = glGenBuffers(); //create a vertex buffer
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, verBufId); //bind the buffer for loading
    FloatBuffer vBuf = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(verts.length*7);
    //load positions in first
    for(Vec v : verts)
        vBuf.put(v.x).put(v.y).put(v.z);//XYZ(openGL assigns W to 1)
    //then load colors in
    for(int i = 0; i < verts.length; i++)
        vBuf.put(color[i].x).put(color[i].y).put(color[i].z).put(color[i].w);//RGBA
    vBuf.rewind();//needs to be rewound before sending
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vBuf, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    //index buffer initialization
    iBufId = glGenBuffers();//create buffer, as above
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, iBufId);//bind, this time to element array
    IntBuffer iBuf = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(faces.length*3);//3 verts per face
    for(Face f : faces) iBuf.put(f.ind[0]).put(f.ind[1]).put(f.ind[2]);//123
    iBuf.rewind();//again, rewind first
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, iBuf, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    //initialize VAO with VBOs, similar to drawing
    verArrId = glGenVertexArrays();
    glBindVertexArray(verArrId);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, verBufId);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 4, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, verts.length*3);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, iBufId);

    glBindVertexArray(0);

    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glCullFace(GL_BACK);
    glFrontFace(GL_CW);
    if(shaders != null){
        shadHandles = new int[shaders.length];
        for(int i = 0; i < shaders.length; i++)
            shadHandles[i] = ShaderLib.createShader(shaders[i]);
        shadProg = ShaderLib.createProgram(shadHandles);
        if(uniforms != null){
            this.unif = ShaderLib.getUniforms(shadProg, uniforms);
            glUseProgram(shadProg);
            glUniformMatrix4(unif.get("camToClip").intValue(), false,
                world.camToClip.asBuf());
            glUseProgram(0);
        }
    }
}

public void draw() {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glUseProgram(shadProg);

    glBindVertexArray(verArrId);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, faces.length*3, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
    /* diagnostic. to see the final vertex locations in OpenGL
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        System.out.println(world.camToClip.mult(verts[i]).toString());
    */
    glBindVertexArray(0);
    glUseProgram(0);
}

public boolean init(){
    glClearColor(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0f); // I prefer grey
    //Depth stuff
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_CLAMP);
    glClearDepth(1); //clear the depth buffer as the back of the screen
    glDepthMask(true);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);
    glDepthRange(0, 1);
    return true;
}
```

These are the values assigned to the vertex shader's `gl_Position` variable.

```
<-0.4, -0.6, -2.8>
<0.6, -0.6, -2.8>
<0.6, 0.4, -2.8>
<-0.4, 0.4, -2.8>
<-0.4, -0.6, 2.2>
<0.6, -0.6, 2.2>
<0.6, 0.4, 2.2>
<-0.4, 0.4, 2.2>
```

Why doesn't this render anything?

Comment: Have you tried to switch off culling to see if something is drawn afterwards?

Comment: Disabling all the culling didn't fix it. :(

Comment: The last parameter to `glVertexAttribPointer` should be `verts.length * 3 * 4` because it is the offset in bytes.